# Python requests measure response time

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, response

I am trying to measure the response time of a website but I am getting errors.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

time= requests.get("http://google.com").elapsed.total_seconds()

print time
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    time= requests.get("http://google.com").elapsed.total_seconds()
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'elapsed'
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: What `requests` version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: @user3580316 It's working here too.. I'm using Requests version 2.8.1 (via `print requests.__version__ `)

Comment: The latest version is `2.9.1`.

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade requests` in your terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.elapsed` attribute was introduced in `requests` 1.2.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/087de5232c526f5a37dafdeeb7540ba79af44eed/HISTORY.rst#120-2013-03-31)). Update the package:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Comment: Is there an alternative for `elapsed` for `request` version before 1.2.0?